# what is difference between include c file and giving as a parameter in C?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I have 2 c files. first is `main.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include "file.c"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    fonk0(5);
    fonk1();
    return 0;       
}
```

and second is `file.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
int aa;
void fonk0(int a)
{
    aa=a;
}

void fonk1()
{
    printf("aa is : %d \n", aa);
}
```

When I compile these files I use this command:

```
gcc -Wall main.c file.c -o main1
```

it gives warnings

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:7:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘fonk0’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  fonk0(5);
  ^
main.c:8:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘fonk1’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  fonk1();
  ^
```

and `main1` file is 7104 bytes.

After that I added `#include "file.c"` line to `main.c` and compile it again with this command

```
gcc -Wall main.c -o main2
```

it gives no warnings

and `main2` file is 7072 bytes.

`main1` and `main2` works correctly. So what is the difference between these ways ? Why `main1` and `main2` has different file size ? and which way I should use ?

I used `debian 8.5` and `gcc 4.9.2`.

Thanks.

Comment: You should use neither of your ways. Create a header file with declaretions of functions and `#include` it.

Comment: I think the size difference comes from the prototypes of fonk# functions. When they are not included the compiler "guess" they are functions and allocate some space to store info about them. When they are included that is done elsewhere

Comment: adding the lines " void fonk0(int );" and  "void fonk1(void );" in main.c as predeclarations, should make it work

Comment: The important topics that you probably want to research are "translation unit" and "linkage".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get the warning because there is no visible function declaration to the code in main. You need to create a header file "file.h" with the function prototypes inside, then include that header from main.c and file.c both.

Never `#include` .c files. It never makes sense and the need for doing so always originates from bad program design.